# Using RTK Query API paginate, got records of previous page, when there is no such query key in state tree

Tags: redux, pagination, rtk-query

api:

```
export const feedsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'feeds',
  tagTypes: ['Feeds'],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000',
  }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getFeedsByPage: build.query<FeedType[], string>({
      query: (page = '1') => `feeds?_page=${page}`,
      providesTags: (feeds, error, arg) => {
        return feeds
          ? [
              ...feeds.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Feeds', id } as const)),
              { type: 'Feeds', id: 'LIST' },
            ]
          : [{ type: 'Feeds', id: 'LIST' }]
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

component:

```
const FeedsPaginationPage: React.FunctionComponent<
  FeedsPaginationPageProps
> = () => {
  const [query] = useSearchParams()
  const page = query.get('page') ?? '1'
  const { isLoading, data: feeds, isFetching } = useGetFeedsByPageQuery(page,{
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true
  })

  console.log('>>>', isLoading, feeds, isFetching, page)

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        'loading'
      ) : (
        <>
          <button
            className="btn btn-link"
            onClick={() => navigate(`?page=${+page - 1}`)}
          >
            previous
          </button>{' '}
          <button
            className="btn btn-link"
            onClick={() => navigate(`?page=${+page + 1}`)}
          >
            next
          </button>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

I.e. there are 100 feeds:

When I visit page<2> from page<1>, I get `feeds` always an array of page<1>'s data(10 records), but in the state tree, obviously there is no such data. When `useGetFeedsByPageQuery("2")` is called, the feeds should be undefined, I don't understand why .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook will keep the previous data in `data` as long as it is loading the new data so you can display it without flickering to an empty screen for a split second. You can always check `isFetching` to see if the data is just being fetched and the displayed data might be stale, or access `currentData` instead of `data`.

Comment: Thanks! ```currentData``` that's what I need!